# How can I split a column into 2?

Tags: pandas

I have the following df:

```
                    0
0    Fuerte venta (0,00)*
1   Infraponderar (0,00)*
2        Neutral (14,00)*
3   Sobreponderar (2,00)*
4  Fuerte compra (11,00)*
```

How could I split the column into 2 columns in order to obtain the following output:

```
           0         1
0    Fuerte venta (0,00)*
1   Infraponderar (0,00)*
2        Neutral (14,00)*
3   Sobreponderar (2,00)*
4  Fuerte compra (11,00)*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use str.rsplit

```
pd.DataFrame(df['0'].str.rsplit(' ', 1).tolist())
```

You get

```
    0               1
0   Fuerte venta    (0,00)*
1   Infraponderar   (0,00)*
2   Neutral         (14,00)*
3   Sobreponderar   (2,00)*
4   Fuerte compra   (11,00)*
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`.str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html#pandas-series-str-rsplit) with `expand=True`:

```
df['0'].str.rsplit(' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

Output:

```
               0         1
0   Fuerte venta   (0,00)*
1  Infraponderar   (0,00)*
2        Neutral  (14,00)*
3  Sobreponderar   (2,00)*
4  Fuerte compra  (11,00)*
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
list comprehension and `str.rsplit`
`pir2`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame([x.rsplit(' ', 1) for x in df['0'].values.tolist()])
)

               0         1
0   Fuerte venta   (0,00)*
1  Infraponderar   (0,00)*
2        Neutral  (14,00)*
3  Sobreponderar   (2,00)*
4  Fuerte compra  (11,00)*
```

---

**Option 2**
Using `np.core.defchararray.rsplit`
`pir1`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.core.defchararray.rsplit(df['0'].values.astype(str), ' ', 1).tolist()
)

               0         1
0   Fuerte venta   (0,00)*
1  Infraponderar   (0,00)*
2        Neutral  (14,00)*
3  Sobreponderar   (2,00)*
4  Fuerte compra  (11,00)*
```

---

**Timing**
*Code below*
`list` comprehension is fastest for big and small datasets.

[image]

```
pir1 = lambda d: pd.DataFrame(np.core.defchararray.rsplit(d['0'].values.astype(str), ' ', 1).tolist())
pir2 = lambda d: pd.DataFrame([x.rsplit(' ', 1) for x in d['0'].values.tolist()])
bos = lambda d: d['0'].str.rsplit(' ', n=1, expand=True)
vai = lambda d: pd.DataFrame(d['0'].str.rsplit(' ', 1).tolist())

results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index([10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000]),
    columns='pir1 pir2 bos vai'.split()
)

for i in results.index:
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in results.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        results.set_value(i, j, timeit(stmt, setp, number=100))

results.plot(loglog=True)
```

Comment: You know I normally like being on top, but in this case and many of your other charts where I am frequently on top, I don't think that is so good.

Comment: Now that I'm familiar with your performance preference, I'll make sure to switch my axes. (-:  But seriously, I post these mainly because I wanted to know.  And I figure that I might as well share.

Comment: I appreciate you sharing.  Thank you.

Comment: Amazing how the performance changes with the size of the data. Can you pl elaborate on the LC solution?

Comment: @piRSquared, i think it's time to write your own advanced timeit module ! ;-)

Comment: @Vaishali at its heart, its the same as your solution.  The difference is that I'm use a list comprehension to iterate through a list while creating a list of lists.  Your solution is leveraging `pandas` to perform the same `rsplit` via the `pd.Series.str` accessor.  I'm not certain, but `pandas` may, in fact, be using a comprehension under the hood.  However, that call returns a `pd.Series` of lists.  Where upon you call `tolist()` and `pd.DataFrame`.  I've reduced overhead by skipping one or two of those constructor steps.