# Struggle changing format in df and not sure why

Tags: pandas

I had an initial list , which I turned to a df:

```
 ['Fuerte venta (0,00)*', 'Infraponderar (0,00)*', 'Neutral (14,00)*', 'Sobreponderar (2,00)*', 'Fuerte compra (11,00)*']

                  1
 0
Fuerte venta    (0,00)*
Infraponderar   (0,00)*
Neutral        (14,00)*
Sobreponderar   (2,00)*
Fuerte compra  (11,00)*
```

Then in order to remove the undesired substrings `' ( ' , ' ) '  and  ' * '` I tried:

```
df1=df.replace({'(':'',')*':''},regex=True)
```

arising the error:

```
sre_constants.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0
```

Then I tried

```
df1=df.replace('(','').replace(')*','')
```

returning the same initial input.

The desired output would be:

```
                  1
 0
Fuerte venta    0,00
Infraponderar   0,00
Neutral         14,00
Sobreponderar   2,00
Fuerte compra  11,00
```

I think the problem is that the datatype of the values is an `array` and that is why the `replace` does not  work at all.

Can anyone help me understand the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700015/how-can-i-split-a-column-into-2/45700097#45700097) with rsplit to this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': ['Fuerte venta (0,00)*', 'Infraponderar (0,00)*', 'Neutral (14,00)*', 'Sobreponderar (2,00)*', 'Fuerte compra (11,00)*']})

df['0'].str.extract('(.*)\s\((.*)\)', expand = True)

    0               1
0   Fuerte venta    0,00
1   Infraponderar   0,00
2   Neutral         14,00
3   Sobreponderar   2,00
4   Fuerte compra   11,00
```